# pgfplot bar chart with no X labels?

Tags: pgfplots

Is it possible to produce a bar chart in `pgfplots` with no X labels?  I'd like to simply fill the bars and have an external legend that provides a color code.  I'm making a `3x1` group plot that shows the performance of several different algorithms under three different sets of assumptions, and so the X labels would just be repeated which starts to really crowd the space.  But I can't seem to find anything about how to generate a bar chart with no X labels...

Here's a sort of MWE...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                footonotesize,
                group style={
                group size=3 by 1,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                ylabels at=edge left
                }]
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Empirical CDF}]
                \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                    (1, 8.501)
                    (2, 10.179)
                    (3, 11.14)
                    (4, 15.001)
                    (5, 6.886)};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Triangular CDF}]
                \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                    (1, 7.745)
                    (2, 8.606)
                    (3, 8.630)
                    (4, 15.001)
                    (5, 6.886)};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize LN/Exponential CDF}]
                \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                    (1, 8.428)
                    (2, 9.964)
                    (3, 11.087)
                    (4, 15.001)
                    (5, 6.886)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    %\ref{CombinedLegendBar}
    \caption{Triage++ Performance}
    \label{PlusPlusCombinedBar}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It looks horrible at the moment :)  I'm still figuring out pgfplots.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a MWE? ;-)

Comment: OP edited to include a sort of MWE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use `xtick=\empty` or `xticklabels=\empty`. In first case both ticks and labels are gone while in the latter only labels are gone. Here I have put `xticklabels=\empty`.

```
\documentclass[border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                group style={
                group size=3 by 1,
                xlabels at=edge bottom,
                ylabels at=edge left,                
                }]
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Empirical CDF},xticklabels=\empty]
                \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                    (1, 8.501)
                    (2, 10.179)
                    (3, 11.14)
                    (4, 15.001)
                    (5, 6.886)};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Triangular CDF},xticklabels=\empty]
                \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                    (1, 7.745)
                    (2, 8.606)
                    (3, 8.630)
                    (4, 15.001)
                    (5, 6.886)};
            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize LN/Exponential CDF},xticklabels=\empty]
                \addplot[ybar] coordinates {
                    (1, 8.428)
                    (2, 9.964)
                    (3, 11.087)
                    (4, 15.001)
                    (5, 6.886)};
        \end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Now on to working out the legend!  And the fills.  And the error bars.  :)